RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded when deploying Flask app with Gunicorn on Azure
I'm deploying a Flask app to Azure, and I'm running into a RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded error that only occurs when the app is deployed. The same code works perfectly fine locally.
Error Message:
/opt/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/ssl.py\", line 604, in minimum_version\n    super(SSLContext, SSLContext).minimum_version.__set__(self, value)\n  [Previous line repeated 476 more times]\nRecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded\n

Here’s the relevant part of my code:
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
encoded_payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf-8')
response = http.request('POST', url, body=encoded_payload, headers=headers)   
response_data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))           

Deployment Configuration:
I'm using Gunicorn to deploy the app on Azure. Here’s my startup configuration:
Startup command in Azure:
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --worker-class gevent --preload app:app

I also have this startup.txt:
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --worker-class gevent app:app

When I remove the startup command in Azure, the request is successful, but other parts of the code that involve WebSockets stop working.
The error doesn't occur locally, only when the app is deployed on Azure. And I think the recursion error seems to be related to SSL context creation and handling, but I'm unsure why this would cause a recursion loop.
Update
I initially encountered this issue using a confidential URL, but I was able to reproduce the same RecursionError using a public API. Below is a minimal reproduction of the problem.
Setup Flask Application:
Create a basic Flask application with an endpoint that triggers an HTTP POST request using urllib3.
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import urllib3
import urllib.parse
import json
import traceback

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"  # Public API for testing
    payload = {
        "title": "foo",
        "body": "bar",
        "userId": 1
    }
    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json"  # JSON content type for this API
    }
    try:
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        encoded_payload = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')  # JSON payload for the public API
        response = http.request(
            'POST',
            url,
            body=encoded_payload,
            headers=headers
        )
        
        response_data = json.loads(response.data.decode('utf-8'))

        return jsonify(response_data)
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return jsonify({"error": str(e), "trace": traceback.format_exc()}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Deploy the Flask App to Azure Using Gunicorn:
Deploy the application to Azure using Gunicorn. Here’s the startup command I used:
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --worker-class gevent --preload app:app

startup.txt file:
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --worker-class gevent app:app

Reproduce the Issue:
Deploy the application to Azure and access the root endpoint (/). This should trigger the RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded error.
Expected vs Actual Behavior:
Expected Behavior: The application should process the request and return the expected JSON response from the public API.
Actual Behavior: The application raises a RecursionError, seemingly related to SSL context handling, though the root cause may be elsewhere in the code.
Note:
This error occurs with both the public API and the confidential URL I originally used, suggesting that the issue might be related to the deployment environment or specific settings in Azure when using Gunicorn.

"Here’s the relevant part of my code" ... "I think the recursion error seems to be related to SSL context creation and handling, but I'm unsure why this would cause a recursion loop" No, it's not in the TLS stuff.  It's in your code, but I don't see anything in the part you called relevant.  Can you provide a minimal reproduction of the issue?

Updated. Thanks!


"/opt/python/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 604, in minimum_version\n super(SSLContext, SSLContext).minimum_version.set(self, value)\n [Previous line repeated 476 more times]\nRecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded\n"

This issue arises when using specific configurations with Gunicorn, such as the gevent worker class and the --preload option.

The gevent worker class cause issues with SSL in some environments, leading to recursion errors. This is because gevent changes how I/O operations, including SSL handling, are managed.

Switching to the sync or eventlet worker class, which might handle SSL differently.
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --worker-class sync app:app


Remove the --preload option from your Gunicorn command. This command preloads the application code before the worker processes are forked. This can lead to recursion errors in environments with specific SSL configurations

Disable SSL verification to see if the recursion issue is directly tied to SSL handling.
response = http.request(
    'POST',
    url,
    body=encoded_payload,
    headers=headers,
    cert_reqs='CERT_NONE'  # Disable SSL verification
)

